# converting datetime from wmiobject to datetime

Tags: powershell, datetime, typeconverter, get-wmiobject

Trying to get the difference in days between to dates: Today's date. and a date/time from a wmiobject (this was taken from a post from the PendingReboot script from Hey, Scripting! blog):

```
$Lastreboottime = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $Computer | 
select csname, @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION=$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}} 
$Today = Get-Date -Format d
$DiffDays = $Today - $Lastreboottime
```

The result of $Today is

```
09/06/2016
```

and $Lastreboottime is

```
05/05/2016 11:13:21
```

So I want to get rid of the time but not sure how to do this.

Secondly, I get this error if I were to run the script, though I guess this may go away if I am able to extract the date only in $Lastreboot

```
Cannot convert the "@{csname=JDWTAWEB1; LastBootUpTime=05/05/2016 11:13:21}" value of type "Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject" to type "System.DateTime".
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove `-Format d` and compare the `Date`-properties of the `DateTime`-objects to get the days-diff only.
2. Your `$Lastreboottime`-variable references an object with both computername `csname` and the `LastBootUpTime`, so you need to access the `LastBootUpTime`

Try:

```
$Lastreboottime = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | 
select csname, @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}

$Today = Get-Date
$DiffDays = $Today.Date - $Lastreboottime.LastBootUpTime.Date

$DiffDays.TotalDays
13
```

Comment: How can we achieve this in below CSV format?

Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem |  ConvertTo-Csv | ConvertFrom-Csv | select csname, @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}

Answer (score 1):

I think that the WMIObject conversion might need to get to a Datetime object by way of a properly formatted string.  I did this (minus the `-Computername $Computer` part) and it seemed to work.

```
[string]$BootTimeString=(Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $Computer).lastbootuptime -replace '\..*',''

$BootTimeDT=[datetime]::ParseExact($BootTimeString,'yyyyMMddHHmmss',$null)

$DiffDays = (NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $BootTimeDT –End (Get-Date)).Days
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `-Format d` from `Get-Date`. You need `DateTime` object, not a string.
2. `$Lastreboottime` is an object with 2 properties: `csname` and `lastbootuptime`. You have to use `lastbootuptime` property.

#### Example:

```
$Today = Get-Date
$DiffDays = $Today - $Lastreboottime.lastbootuptime
```